# How can I detect Empty Content as input content in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a **CustomView** which has a simple logic! If this **CustomView** get a non EmptyView should return an HStack, and If this **CustomView** get an EmptyView should return a Circle, how could I find out the right option depending on input content?

---

***for example it should work like this: But it does not! I must hard code true or false for the result you see in down***

```
CustomView() { Text("Hello") }.background(Color.red).padding()
```

[image]

---

```
CustomView().background(Color.red)
```

[image]

---

**Goal:** This question try find an answer to set right value for `useHStack` value depending on input content!

***PS: Logically there is a way to use `useHStack` as parameter of **CustomView**, in this case there was no need to ask this question! So we are trying solve the issue without using `useHStack` as input parameter of **CustomView** or any other also! I like detect at initialization on CustomView not in body or through GeometryReader and so on . . .***

**My issue is there, how can I know when `useHStack` must be true or false depending on incoming content!** *incoming content* means from example: Text("Hello")

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        CustomView() { Text("Hello") }
        
        CustomView()
        
    }
}



struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    let useHStack: Bool
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        
        self.content = content
        self.useHStack = true // or: false depending on content(), if we got EmptyView() then false otherwise true! the idea is make this part Automatic!
        
    }
    
    init() where Content == EmptyView {
        
        self.init(content: { EmptyView() })

    }
    
    var body: some View {

        if useHStack {
            
            HStack {
                
                content()
                
                Spacer()
                
                Circle().frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                
            }
            
        }
        else {
            
            Circle().frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            
        }
 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "incoming content"? the content is static - so you know at compile time what the content is

Comment: sorry, maybe I use wrong naming, you tell me the correct one, I edit it, I mean like this:  `CustomView() { incoming content }`

Comment: It's not the naming.. i don't understand what you mean? Why doesn't work in your current solution?

Comment: I have zero solution!

Comment: The code you included - what doesn't work there? You seem to have the right init for the `EmptyView` case - set the `useHStack` there

Comment: I think I could not explained it well, sorry for that, let me try here, If I use this code: `CustomView() { Text("Hello") }.background(Color.red).padding()` here we got `Text("Hello")` and **useHStack** should be automatically set to **true**. but if I got this code: `CustomView().background(Color.red)` that means we got `EmptyView ()` and **useHStack** should be automatically set to **false**. right now what you see in code I am hard coding true or false! the idea is make it automatically depending on incoming content!

Comment: Well, why not set `self.useHStack = false` in the `init() where Content == EmptyView`

Comment: Have you success? I tried before asking this question! Xcode did not let me do it! Xcode said: `'let' property 'useHStack' may not be initialized directly; use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." instead`

Comment: LoL I think I must used it as `var` not `let`! :)))

Comment: @NewDev: I am so thankful for your time and help, previously I got that Xcode massage, but I did not read it well at first place, while telling you I read it again, and I found the issue, but you told me first.

Comment: You can keep it as `let`, but then you'd need a private `init` to set everything there.

Comment: can you show me that code plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `useHStack` to false inside the `init() where Content == EmptyView`. You either would need to make it `var useHStack: Bool`, or create a `private init`:

```
private init(content: @escaping () -> Content, useHStack: Bool) {
    self.content = content
    self.useHStack = useHStack
}

init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.init(content: content, useHStack: true)
}

init() where Content == EmptyView {
    self.init(content: { EmptyView() }, useHStack: false)
}
```

Comment: After all things we spoke or code, could not we directly see inside content at first place? I know it is not possible for us, but I want be sure. in this case we would not need even use `useHStack`, because we could read or look inside content inside body as well, for example if is Empty do this or if not do that.

Comment: @swiftPunk, SwiftUI view is statically known. Sure, you can detect `EmptyView` here, but it wouldn't work if you had something like `if someCondition { EmptyView } else { Text("not empty") }` - i.e. this wouldn't detect if the view at runtime became "empty". So, you need to clarify to yourself what you're after and what it means to "see inside"

Comment: No, I wanted ask this code, if we can do this: `var body: some View {  if content() != EmptyView() { return HStack {} } else { return Circle() } }` in this case it would be much easier for us!

Comment: I mean.. you can always check the type.. something like `if type(of: content) == (() -> EmptyView).self {..}`

Comment: Maybe you can add this code to your answer as well, for full cover!  `init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) where Content == EmptyView { self.init(content: content, useHStack: false) }`

Comment: that doesn't feel like it belongs to the question, and it's also necessarily the most elegant approach

Comment: If we use this code `CustomView() { EmptyView() }` or `CustomView() {}` then we need that, but about condition of question you are right! thanks again for help